# xml to linq query write

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an xDocument object and which is loaded through an xml file which contains below given data.

```
<note>
   <header>This is xml2linq -- Part1.</header>
   <from>From me</from>
   <to>to stackoverflow</to>
   <message>ohh wow</message>
</note>
<note>
   <header>This is xml2linq -- Part2 .</header>
   <to>to stackoverflow</to>
   <message>ohh wow</message>
</note>
<note>
   <header>This is xml2linq -- Part3 .</header>
   <from>From me</from>
   <to>to stackoverflow</to>
</note>
<description>
  <item1>ohh nice</item1>
</description>
<description>
   <language>c-sharp</language>
   <item1>Inheritance</item1>
<description>
```

I want to write linq query on xDocument and get the below given Output

```
 note(header,from,to,message)
 description(item1,language)
```

** Description.
I want the distinct list of node names which are followed by Note node. But I dont want to write a long foreach or for loop. But I want to write a simple linq query on the xDocument object.

Help me to get this output...

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: What do you mean by "get the below given output"? A sequence of `Note` objects, or actual strings?

Comment: Are you going to accept an answer?

Comment: If you have a *new* question, ask a *new* question, do *not* completely change the existing question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(" -- your XML here -- ");
var notes = from note in doc.Elements("note")
            select new {
                Header = (string)note.Element("header"),
                From = (string)note.Element("from"),
                To = (string)note.Element("to"),
                Message = (string)note.Element("message"),
            };
```

This will give you a list of anonymous objects with 4 properties: Header, From, To and Message.

Comment: Here my xml contains many different nodes expect Note only. So i cant hardcode it with header, from, to etc element name inside the query.

Comment: Does not do a null-check. And he asked to return string.

Answer (score 0):

Without harcoded `header,from,to,..` etc.

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(....);

List< List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> > list =
    xDoc.Descendants("note")
    .Select(note => note.Elements()
                        .Select(e => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(e.Name.LocalName, e.Value))
                        .ToList())
    .ToList();
```